# Error returning for-loop with array encapsulation in C

Tags: c, arrays

Been working on an essay of mine and i stumble upon this weird thing. For some reason the following snippet is responsible for the failing of my programm.

```
for(i=0; i< DOC; i++){
        for(j=0;j<MAXWORDS;i++){
            average[list[i]][j]+=array[i][j];
        }  
    }
    for(i=0; i< k; i++){
        for(j=0;j<MAXWORDS;i++){
            k_array[i][j]=(average[i][j]/count[i]);
        }  
    }
```

I'm on linux and gcc

Comment: Both inner loops: Are you sure you want to increase `i` and not `j`?

Comment: Also, what's `average[]`, `array[][]` and `list[]` ? You're missing a `]` right before the assignement operator.

Comment: @chrk: All brackets accounted for. Though the rest ...

Comment: @Deduplicator Oh just noticed, indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure what you are going for but on

```
for(j=0;j<MAXWORDS;i++){
```

you are incrementing i not j so it seems as though you have an infinite loop.

Comment: Well.. that's it. And i couldn't see it cause i was looking at the function. Propably some error there, but no. The error once again was human based. Thanks for the extra eye

Comment: No problem. It is that way in both just in case you didn't notice the 2nd one.